# optional one-to-one formatting python

Tags: python

```
var_dic={
    'var1':'string test1',
    'var2':'strig test2',
    'var3':'string test3'
}
string_dic={
    'test1':{'var':{'var1'},
            'text':'food {var1}'
            },
    'test2':
        {'var':{'var1','var2'},
            'text':'food {var1} food {var2}'
            },
    'test3':{'var':{'var3'},
            'text':'food {var3}'
            }
}
```

Hi I have these two data dictionaries in python and I need to add the values ​​from the first to the second.
the variables that each text will have in the second dictionary vary.
Also the number of var can be huge. so adding all variables to string.format() is not an option.
According to the documentation all the keys of a string are mandatory, so I cannot do the following:

```
string_dic[test2][text].format(var1=var_dic['var1'])
string_dic[test2][text].format(var2=var_dic['var2'])
```

I was trying something like the following, but I can't find a way to make it work.

```
for a in string_dic:
    for b in string_dic[a]['var']:
        print(string_dic[a]['text'].format(=var_dic[b]))
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Was `string_dic` always a dictionary or did you read it as a string and then converted to dic?

Comment: `string_dic['test2']['var']` has a set `{'var1','var2'}`, and some `var`s appear inside strings and between `{ }`. What are the criteria to deal with these cases. E.g. `'food {var1} food {var2}'` should become `'food {string test1} food {string test2}'` or `'food string test1 food string test2'`?

Comment: Maybe in your top-level workflow, you could use `dict.update()`, I will paste official doc here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly come from reading a yaml file. and 'food {var1} food {var2}' should become 'food string test1 food string test2'. 
Thank you very much for the help..

Comment: If you are reading a text file, you could do the replacements before parsing it with [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), and deal with the cases `{varX}` and `'varX'` separately. I guess iterating through the keys of `var_dic` and building the strings by adding the `{ }`s and `' '`s should do it.